# Publish App On AppExchange

Tags: appexchange, partner-portal

I want to publish my app as free app on Salesforce AppExchange. I have already joined ISV partner portal through http://www.salesforce.com/partners/join/ and selected "AppExchange Partner Program". And I have read in salesforce packaging guide that for releasing the app I only need to register on partner portal which I had already done.

I also created a case through it but I got replied "Have you looked at our partnerships yet? You need to sign up for one in order to list on the AppExchange." and they provided http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/program-models/ link.

Now do I have to register for AppExchange Partner Program Model separately, if yes then please guide me where can I do so because I didn't find any register link on there AppExchange Partner Program Models page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> I also created a case through it but I got replied "Have you looked at our partnerships yet? You need to sign up for one in order to list on the AppExchange." and they provided http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/program-models/ link.

If you go to the [AppExchange Partner Programs Page](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/program-models/) that's linked from the one you were given, you'll see two options for business models that partners can choose from. Even though yours will be free, you'll still need to choose. There's a link to a PDF at the bottom of that page you'll want to download. BTW, you'll want to choose the option on the left since I'm confident you don't want to "sell" a free app from your own web site.

There's a "Live Chat" tab on the right hand edge of that page you can click on to get any of your questions answered.